# Unknown artifact sbtplugin Super safe compiler with scala 2.12

Tags: scalatest, sbt-plugin, scala-2.12

In my sbt project in Scala 2.12 I am using IntelliJ IDEA and want to import scalatest.
In order to install the *recommended SuperSafe Community Edition Scala compiler plugin*. I followed the instruction [here](http://www.scalatest.org/supersafe).

My *plugin.sbt*:

`addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.2")`

the error showed by the Intellij import is:

```
        SBT project import
        [warn]  [FAILED     ] com.artima.supersafe#sbtplugin;1.1.2!sbtplugin.jar(src):  (0ms)
        [warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
        [warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.artima.supersafe/sbtplugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.2/srcs/sbtplugin-sources.jar
        [warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
        [warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.artima.supersafe/sbtplugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.2/srcs/sbtplugin-sources.jar
        [warn] ==== local: tried
        [warn]   /Users/salvob/.ivy2/local/com.artima.supersafe/sbtplugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.2/srcs/sbtplugin-sources.jar
        [warn] ==== public: tried
        [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/artima/supersafe/sbtplugin_2.10_0.13/1.1.2/sbtplugin-1.1.2-sources.jar
        [warn] ==== Artima Maven Repository: tried
        [warn]   http://repo.artima.com/releases/com/artima/supersafe/sbtplugin_2.10_0.13/1.1.2/sbtplugin-1.1.2-sources.jar
        [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        [warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS     ...
```

Maybe incompatility with new Scala Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- When we add the plug-in in projects/build.sbt:

  `addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.2")`
- We must **not** add the above plug-in anywhere else
- Add to `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`

  `resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"`
- Do **not** add this resolver anywhere else
- Make sure you have an empty line before and after each of the sbt lines

  HTHs