# unresolved dependency: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.4;1.1.3: not found

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am trying to use scala test and write:

```
resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.3")
```

into `plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt` looks as following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % ScalaTest,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % ScalaTest % "test"
)
```

`SBT` complains:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[error]   at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.4;1.1.3: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.4;1.1.3: not found
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Nov 23, 2017 1:58:40 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/home/developer/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/home/developer/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42444449/5775077

Comment: I could not find the file `global.sbt` in the folder `~/.sbt/1.0`, so do I have to create it by myself?

Comment: yes. I think so. See [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Global-Settings.html)

Comment: So as I understood from doc, I have to create by myself but do I have to restart the computer?

Comment: afaik, it is not necessary.

Comment: Now I've got following warning: `[error] server failed to start on 127.0.0.1:5168. java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)`. What does it mean?

Comment: That seems not related to sbt anymore. However, that message states that some other process on your machine is using port 5168. BTW, are now you able to resolve sbtplugin dependency?

Comment: OK, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding the resolver to the **sbt global**, as suggested in https://www.artima.com/supersafe_user_guide.html

Add the Artima Maven Repository as a resolver in **~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt**, like this:

```
resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
```

I had it in the build.sbt file and moving it as per their instructions solved the issue for me.
Good luck!

Comment: Add more information, mind the path of the `global.sbt` file, yours might be a little bit different. To know exactly what the path is, go inside `~/.sbt/<version>`. `<version>` is automatically created as `sbt` ran. Some of yours is `0.13`, others might be `1.0`

Comment: The [Scala Test install guide](http://www.scalatest.org/install) blindly asserts `0.13`, and I was too dumb to notice I'm actually using `1.0`. Pay attention to this line in your console: `[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/xxx/.sbt/1.0/plugins`. Thanks @KenBlock