# How do I add an SBT plugin resolver on CircleCI?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, circleci

I am trying to automate CI/CD of a small Scala project using CircleCI. The project is built using `sbt`, and tested using the ScalaTest library.

As per the [ScalaTest installation instruction's](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide) recommendation, I am using the SuperSafe compiler plugin, which required me to add a resolver to global file `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt`:

```scala
resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
```

I can successfully compile and test my project locally. however on CircleCI the build fails with error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.8;1.1.7: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.artima.supersafe:supersafe_2.12.8:1.1.7 (Defaults.scala#L3331)
[warn]        +- filesystem:filesystem_2.12:0.1
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.8;1.1.7: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.12.8;1.1.7: not found
```

This error is to be expected when the required resolver hasn't been added in SBT -- see e.g. [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456328/unresolved-dependency-com-artima-supersafesupersafe-2-12-41-1-3-not-found). I am new to CircleCI and don't know where its SBT globals dir would be located, or how to modify the file.

Instead I've tried to add the resolver to my project's `./project/plugins.sbt` file directly, but this has not fixed the issue.

The SBT and CircleCI config files look as follows:

`./build.sbt`

```
name := "my-project-name"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % "test"
```

`./project/build.properties`

```
sbt.version = 1.2.8
```

`./project/plugins.sbt`

```scala
resolvers += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.7")
```

`./.circleci/config.yml`
(the default Scala config provided by CircleCI)

```
# Scala CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/postgres:9.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      # Customize the JVM maximum heap limit
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.sbt" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: cat /dev/null | sbt test:compile

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies--{{ checksum "build.sbt" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: cat /dev/null | sbt test:test
```

I want a successful CircleCI build, which will require a way to add the resolver, either in the project's own files or declaring it in the SBT globals file of the CircleCI container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider open issue [SBT isn't using resolvers defined in project/plugins.sbt #4103](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4103). Try scoping the resolver to `ThisBuild` and put it in **both** `build.sbt` and `plugins.sbt` like so:

```
// someApp/build.sbt
resolvers in ThisBuild += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
```

and

```
// someApp/project/plugins.sbt
resolvers in ThisBuild += "Artima Maven Repository" at "http://repo.artima.com/releases"
addSbtPlugin("com.artima.supersafe" % "sbtplugin" % "1.1.7")
```

This seems to have worked on this example [repo](https://github.com/mario-galic/how-do-i-add-an-sbt-plugin-resolver-on-circleci)